# Converter coluna do tipo LONG em VARCHAR2 no ORACLE - problema relacionado ao tamanho do valor da coluna do tipo LONG em relação ao VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle, funções, varchar, longblob

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRC_HAM_CONVT_LONG_VARCHAR2
( p_owner VARCHAR2, p_tabela VARCHAR2, p_coluna VARCHAR2, p_rowid UROWID    )RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

     v_cursor INTEGER; --cursor
     v_length INTEGER; --tamanho do long
     v_tamanho INTEGER; --tamanho do que foi retornado
     v_sql VARCHAR(2000); --stetament
     v_max VARCHAR2(32760); --variavel varchar2 com tamanho maximo do long
     v_clob CLOB; --variavel do tipo clob
     v_long LONG; --variavel do tipo long
     v_syscur SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
v_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

v_sql := 'SELECT '||p_coluna||' FROM '||p_owner||'.'||p_tabela||' WHERE ROWID = :row_id';

OPEN v_syscur FOR v_sql USING p_rowid;
FETCH v_syscur INTO v_long;
v_length := LENGTH(v_long);
CLOSE v_syscur;    
dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor,v_sql,dbms_sql.NATIVE);
dbms_sql.bind_variable(v_cursor,'row_id',p_rowid);
dbms_sql.define_column_long(v_cursor,1);    

IF(dbms_sql.execute_and_fetch(v_cursor) = 1) THEN
   dbms_sql.column_value_long( v_cursor, 1, v_length, 0, v_max, v_tamanho );
END IF;  

dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob, FALSE, dbms_lob.CALL);
v_clob := v_max;

RETURN v_max; --OU ENTAO V_MAX

END;
```

Com essa função acima do Oracle consigo converter uma coluna do tipo LONG normalmente para VARCHAR2, porém, existem casos em que o valor da coluna LONG ultrapassa a faixa permitida do VARCHAR2 o que inevitavelmente causa um erro, como eu poderia fazer para resolver esse problema? Ou seja, fazer com que todo o valor da coluna LONG seja convertida para VARCHAR2?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**
Acredito que não é possível.

---

A pergunta, base é, por que precisa ser `varchar2`? Esse tipo armazena somente 4000 bytes<sup>1</sup>, enquanto o `LONG`no máximo 2GB, logicamente a conversão iria perder dados, pois não "cabe" a quantidade de informações em um `varchar2`.

Sugiro que:

- Trabalhe com esse tipo de dados na aplicação que esta desenvolvendo;
- Cortar a quantidade caracteres no limite do `varchar2`;
- Algum procedimento técnico criativo. <s>gambiarra</s> . (não recomendado)

<sup><sup>1</sup> Tamanho máximo: *4000 bytes* ou *32767 bytes* se o `MAX_STRING_SIZE` parâmetro de inicialização estiver definido como `EXTENDED`. Fonte: [Oracle - Datatype Limits 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm#i287903)</sup>

Comment: Olá meu nobre obrigado pela resposta. Eu preciso converter para o tipo VARCHAR2 pela necessidade de dar um REPLACE nessa coluna. Como ela é LONG infelizmente não obtive sucesso.